# Eclipse open declaration/implementation hover menu empty

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.6

Running Mac Eclipse Helios SR2, the menu that appears on <kbd>command</kbd>-hovering over a method sometimes comes up empty instead of the usual Declaration/Implementation option:

[image: Empty 'jump to' menu]

The last time this happened, it went back to normal after a few days with no obvious intervention on my part, but I haven't been able to make that happen again this time.  While not debilitating, it's certainly obnoxious and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you open in another workspace?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are referring to the Quick Hierarchy menu then this might help:
http://tamsler.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/eclipse-command-hover-doesnt-show-open.html

Another workaround to bring up "Open Implementation" is to point your cursor to the desired method and use Command+T to bring up this menu.

Comment: If it recurs, I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with a new install of 10.8. As per this post: http://tamsler.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/eclipse-command-hover-doesnt-show-open.html this was a result of the OS X hidden scroll bars option. Once changed, this was resolved for me.